# Constant flickering on my external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I've recorded a 7 second video of it here: http://youtu.be/2k9P59Z32wE. Basically, the screen will alternate between a fuzzy picture, color bars, and then black every ~2 seconds or so.

Technical details: I'm using a mini-DP to dual-DVI adapter with a dell 3007 wfp with a late 2013 macbook pro (with nvidia graphics). I've been using this setup for several months now. I've confirmed it's an OSX issue because my display works with my bootcamp partition, and another windows machine.

This started happening yesterday after my mac froze when I attached it to my display. I had to do a hard reboot, and I suspect this may have corrupted some system files. I've tried doing PRAM/SMC resets, and also following suggestions to delete `com.apple.windowserver.*` files (http://foliovision.com/2009/12/apple-dual-dvi-mini-displayport-adapter-mb571z). No luck so far.

I'm thinking about just doing a fresh install and then migrating my data to fix this. Any better solutions?

edit:
Looks like my adapter is broken. I only tested lower resolutions, not 2560x1600, when on my window machine/bootcamp! Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Sounds like you experienced a kernel panic when you had to hard reboot. Open up Console. Under System Diagnostic reports, look for a file beginning with `kernel_` and ending with `.panic` Create a [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com) of the KP and post link in your reply. Note: if you resetted the NVRAM immediately following the panic, the report would not have been saved. Hard reboots generally don't corrupt system files - I wouldn't jump to this conclusion quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue potentially has to do with corrupt files, you can try booting from the OS X disk and running disk repair to see if that fixes the problem.